# How to link a website with an android app

Tags: android, web, textfield, time-and-attendance

I was wondering how can you link the fields of a website with an app. Like I have a college attendance website where we all check our attendance and then a student made an app on android where we login by entering the student id and password. So how was the person able to send info from the app to the website and get the information?? Thanks in advance! The website is www.websismit.Manipal.edu.

Comment: Can you add some of your code?

Answer (score 0):

See you there are some ways as follows:-

1. you can make an android app having single activity with webview and
   open your site inside the webview. you can also use html 5 and jquery mobile for that.
2. you can make an native application and using web-services you can
   get/set the parameter result.

Answer (score 0):

In thin client mobile applications, we generally deal with lot of data exchange between server and mobile app. Mobile app is nothing but a client. So in order to get/post data from server you have to **write APIs**.
Now writing **restful API** is your choice you can use any on the available language.
I believe your website is up already so just search and you can easily get ways to expose RESTful APIs.

There are different ways to identify client request, for that you should use Access Token to identify the clientID/UserID or whatever id you are maintaining.

For consuming API from android, you can refer to this [tutorial](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/calling-restful-services-from-your-android-app/).